# FreeOrion ship production variables

Tags: freeorion

I'm playing [FreeOrion](http://www.freeorion.org/) (a free 4x game based on Master of Orion), and when I put a ship in the production queue, there are two drop-downs at the top-left which both affect the total number of ships that get built.  But, I don't understand the difference between the two options:

[image: A production queue with the first option selected]

You can see that I can choose 1, 2,3,4,5,10,20,50, or 99; and choosing 2 ends up creating two ships.  But, the other option right beside it also changes the number of ships built, but it seems like choosing that one is slower.

My Question:  What are the the two options changing, besides just # of ships produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing from 1x to 5x, if spending all needed PP, after the same time, 5 of the enqueued ship will be produced.

Increasing from 1⟳ to 5⟳ will produce one ship at a time, but will produce another ship at the same place on the queue each time one is finished. It will take at least 5x as long to build the ships, but only one at a time will be produced.

Increasing both numbers will, for example, build 5 ships at a time, and then build 5 more after those are finished, and continue doing so until 5 groups of 5 ships have been produced.

Comment: I see; So the X is "Batch Size" and the other is "Repeat count".